# Does running make clean after make install affect the installed program?

Tags: disk-usage, make, rust

Upon cloning, building, and installing rust from their github repository I've found it takes up ~2.8 GB on my system. I've got relatively limited space on my machine (100GB), so I was wondering two things:

1. After running `make install` (or `sudo make install`) does running `make clean` effect the installed program (either in general or for rust particularly)?
2. Would `make clean` even be an effective method of regaining storage space; either in this situation, or in general?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The command

```
make clean
```

doesn't affect your installation and it's a good idea to get some space back after the installation.

To install the application again via

```
sudo make install
```

you have to start

```
make
```

first, because all compiled resources in the source folder will be removed after the clean.